# Does persist() on spark by default store to memory or disk?

Tags: database, apache-spark

I'm aware that, on spark, you can change persist() to store data either to memory or disk, but I was wondering what the default is. I've tried searching for this but haven't been able to get a clear answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default storage level of persist is `MEMORY_ONLY` you can find details from [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence). The other option can be `MEMORY_AND_DISK, MEMORY_ONLY_SER , MEMORY_AND_DISK_SERMEMORY_ONLY_2, MEMORY_AND_DISK_2, DISK_ONLY, OFF_HEAP (experimental).`

[Here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-caching.html) is an simple explanation to help you.